# serializer.data is missing some of the data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Context: I am having problem accessing fields which are validated by nested serializers.
I have a very sample model as shown below. 
For 2 of the fields I have their specific serializers. When I try to access the data it returns all the fields except the one validated by the specific serializers.

Models looks like this

```
class Sampler(models.Model):
  sample_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
  sampling_by = JSONField(max_length=100)
  extractions = JSONField(max_length=100)
  max_samples = models.IntegerField(default=100)
```

Serializers

```
class ExtractionsSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
   table_name = serializers.CharField()
   extraction_type = serializers.ChoiceField(["ABC"])
   dependencies = serializers.ListField(child=RecursiveField(), allow_empty=True, required=False)


class SamplingBySerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
"""
    Validate sampling_by
"""
    def to_internal_value(self, samples):
      methods = ["ABC"]
      sampling_not_supported = [sample for sample in samples
                              if sample['by'] not in methods]
       if sampling_not_supported:
          raise ValidationError("{} not in {}".format(sampling_not_supported, methods))

class SamplerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extractions = ExtractionsSerializer(read_only=True)
    sampling_by = SamplingBySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
      model = Sampler
      fields = ('sample_name', 'database', 'schema', 'sampling_by', 'extractions', 'max_samples')
```

Now I do

```
data = {
"database": "postgresql://..",
"sampling_by":[{
    "by":"ABC",
    "value": ["l32=turn_the"]
}],
"max_samples":3,
"extractions" : [{
    "table_name": "person", 
    "extraction_type": "ABC"
}]
}
sampler = SamplerSerializer(data=data)
sampler.is_valid() #returns True
sampler.data => does not contain data of the nested fields. Like the `sampling_by` and `extractions`. Contains all other fields
sampler.validated_data => same problem as above
```

Any help would be appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed the fact that your nested serializers are flagged as `read_only=True`

```
class SamplerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extractions = ExtractionsSerializer(read_only=True)
    sampling_by = SamplingBySerializer(read_only=True)
```

Remove that part, implement the serializer's `create` / `update` and you're good to go.

On a side note, it doesn't make sense to access `serializer.data` when deserializing.

Edit: the authority source is `validated_data`.

Comment: How do I access the data? if not for `serializer.data`

Comment: I did the above as you said. Removed the `read_only=True` and then implemented create for the serializer. But now it gives me the error "to_internal_value() must be implemented" 
I don't quite understand why that error!

Comment: That's probably an issue with RecursiveField.